# How to Customize a TreeMap to sort keys in descending order?

Tags: java, sorting, treemap

I have a piece of code with which I am trying to sort the keys in the `TreeMap` in descending order because when I just use the `TreeMap`, it sorts based on keys, which are in ascending order. The I am getting error is:

> No Suitable Constructor found for TreeMap.

What's wrong here?

```
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.SortedMap;

public class ChangeMachine {


    public TreeMap<Double, Integer> dispenseChange(Double changeAmount, TreeMap<Double, Integer> coinsMap) {
        TreeMap<Double, Integer> coinDispenserMap = new TreeMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<Double, Integer> coin : coinsMap.entrySet()) {
            if (!(changeAmount > coin.getKey())) {
                coinDispenserMap.put(coin.getKey(), 0);
                continue;
            }
            int noOfCoins = (int) (changeAmount / coin.getKey());
            coinDispenserMap.put(coin.getKey(), noOfCoins);
            Double remainder = changeAmount % coin.getKey();
            changeAmount = remainder;
            if (changeAmount == 0.0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return coinDispenserMap;

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChangeMachine ref = new ChangeMachine();
        TreeMap<Double, Integer> coinsMap = new TreeMap<Double, Integer>(new Comparator<Entry<Double, Integer>>() {
            public int compare(Entry<Double, Integer> coin1, Entry<Double, Integer> coin2) {
                return (coin2.getKey().compareTo(coin1.getKey()));
            }
        });
        coinsMap.put(0.25, 10);
        coinsMap.put(0.01, 10);
        coinsMap.put(0.05, 10);
        coinsMap.put(0.10, 10);

        TreeMap<Double, Integer> coinDispenserMap = ref.dispenseChange(0.86, coinsMap);

        for (Map.Entry<Double, Integer> coin : coinDispenserMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(coin.getKey() + " : " + coin.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to compare `Double`s, not `<Entry<Double, Integer>>`

Comment: Thanks. It works!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparator's type is `Entry<Double, Integer>` which needs to be a super-type of the map's key type, which is `Double`. Since `Entry<Double, Integer>` isn't a super-type of `Double`, the [constructor can't be matched](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap-java.util.Comparator-).

Instead, try:

```
Map<Double, Integer> coinsMap =
    new TreeMap<Double, Integer>(new Comparator<Double>() {
        public int compare(Double coin1, Double coin2) {
            return (coin2.compareTo(coin1));
        }
    });
```

Also, for a bit of style, you might want to consider declaring `coinsMap` as `Map<Double, Integer> coinsMap = new TreeMap<>()` as I did in the code snippet above. Check out Josh Bloch's awesome book [Effective Java 2nd Ed.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) (chapter 4 is relevant here) for great advice on Java.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!!

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Comparator<Double> comparator = Double::compare;
Comparator<Double> reverseComparator = comparator.reversed();
Map<Double,Integer> reversedMap = new TreeMap(reverseComparator);
```